# How to implement inbox message with marketing cloud sdk using xamarin forms?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I am new to marketing cloud sdk. Does anyone having experiences with how to implement MobilePush SDK for Inbox Messages in xamarin forms(Android and IOS)?
Any one please help.

Answer (score 1):

The Android MobilePush SDK does not currently, as of 20200825, support Xamarin.  You would need to create your own bindings file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @BillMote . Is there any Marketing Cloud API or any other methods to get the InboxMessages?

Comment: The APIs are not public and we don't recommend that customers use them outside the SDKs as we make no guarantees that they will not change.